# How to configure Provising Profiles for two macs

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I`m using two macs for develop and i configure the certificate and then generate two Provising Profiles, but when i active then and run the application in device from xcode in mac1 it desactive the other.
And from the desactivated i got this error.

[image]

How i supose configure for be activate in both mac?

Comment: are you sure you have your developer certificate on both macs?

Comment: When i create the certificate i just can create one for ios Development.

Comment: it's understood, but you need to install this certificate on both macs then

Answer (score 1):

This happened as the apple WWDR certificate expired... Apple did contact all developers about this:

https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

If you go into keychain access.

1. Click on System
2. Click on Certificates
3. Click on the WWDR certificate (probably expired)
4. Delete it
5. Download the new one
6. Install it on both macs (in System -> Certificates)

Xcode should fix this really, so:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on the `Xcode` menu
3. Click on `Preferences`
4. In preferences click on the `Accounts` tab
5. In accounts select your applicable account (the one which should have the developer profile
6. Click on the view details button
7. At the top, you'll see your certificates. Click `reset` (or create) next to each
8. At the bottom of the page, download each of the provision profiles, Xcode should install them for you

See if that works.

If that again doesn't work, in system prefs, go to "Profiles" delete the one thats giving you issues and repeat the code fix above.

Comment: I also change the WWDR certificate he will expire in 2023.

Comment: In keychain access, have you validated all of your certificates?

Comment: I checked the WWDR and the certificate for develop its fine.

Comment: The problem is when i  create/reset the certificate here in the other mac that become invalid.

Comment: That works fine for one mac, but using two the provising continues become invalid.

Comment: For development, it's one per machine. Unless you manually ad a development provision profile (HIGHLY unadvisable), then you can add multiple machines to one profile.